# how do you make the html so that it goes to the server every time

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page that uses highcharts java script library to display charts. My page is integrated with Single Sign On mechanism provided by CA.

The time out on the SSO is 30 minutes. When I load the page first time, all the links work flawlessly. If the page is idle 30 minutes, SSO times out and the links try to retrieve data from cache.

How would I make the page so that every time a link is clicked the page goes to the server rather than the browser cache?

I tried these with no luck:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you instead go to the root of the problem and prevent the SSO timeout? Have a periodically executing JS function, every 10 minutes or so, that performs a dummy XHR operation on the server (doesn't even need a callback - since you don't care about the result of the call).

Comment: You only declared the HTML page "no cache", to do the same with the XHR calls you need to let the server(!) add an HTTP header that prevents caching of that XHR call. (2 comments because two very different approaches)

Comment: @Mörre, SSO timeout is by design and it needs to be like that. Can you clarify more about your other suggestions?

Comment: You said it is an idle timeout. So prevent the "idle" part and there will be no timeout. It's a computer - you don't have to have a human being frantically wave around with the mouse in order to make the server think someone is doing something, you can do that in software... :)

Comment: @Mörre, can you give me an example of using XHR to address this?

Comment: You use the async IO function of whatever JS library you use, that shouldn't be more than a handful of lines (without indentation you can fit it on one line). And you can have it periodically execute through setTimeout() or setInterval().

Comment: I think I got it. I could write a small script that will execute page.load() every 20 minutes to by pass this problem?